# Is it possible to create namespaces or logical groups to group queries/mutations in GraphQL?

Tags: maven, kotlin, graphql, graphql-spqr

I am using `io.leangen.graphql.spqr` library version `0.10.1` which is the latest version at the moment.

Is it possible to make logical groups to separate queries?

For example, I have the list of queries:

```
borrowBook, lendBook
bookInfo, books
chooseBook, recommendBook
```

All of the queries can go into separate logical groups such as Library, General, Recommendations.

The question is how to make a logical separation in GraphQL Docs?

My stack is used `Kotlin`, `Maven` and `spqr`.

To summarize,

- Is it possible to make a logical separation between the queries in GraphQL Docs?
- If yes, how to do it with `spqr`?

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/163 ... use prefixes